# Consolidate the same image used multiple times in a PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, devexpress

I am generating PDF documents using DevExpress XtraReports.

I am using the same image over and over (in rows of status lights).

The PDF generated seems to duplicate the image definition for each image included.  I would prefer if it included the image once and referenced it wherever it needed another copy - this would drastically reduce the size of my PDF docs.

Is there any way to achieve this using DevExpress or even post processed via a third party application.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

OPT1: I suppose your image is a background or a company logo and the image is the same on all the pages of the pdf. If yes, then create the pdf without the image. Post-process the pdf and add the image on all the pages (you can do that using itext/itextsharp or pdflib).

OPT2: take your actual pdf and convert it using Ghoscript.  Using Ghsoscript you can do a "pdf to pdf" conversion. During the conversion Ghostscript try to identify repeated images and removes them. The resulting file is smaller. (Ghostscript is not always able to do that... try with you pdf file).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to re-use the same image content in multiple locations throughout your document. But it's a fair bit easier to do this while adding the image(s) to the PDF.

I'm not sure if DevExpress supports this.